# How to distribute init. vector with data encrypted via a symmetric cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want to provide for the user a service of encrypting some data via symmetric cipher to a file. The user simply provide a key and he/she may provide an initialize vector for the cipher.

Is there a standard how the file should look like? It makes sense to fill the file with the encrypted data and show the corresponding initialize vector in a dialog window. It may seem reasonable to someone else that the initialize vector should be stored in the file with the encrypted data.

The important thing for me is that the result is useful for a user and he/she won't need to bother with adjustment of the result.

Thank for a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to provide the IV as the first block of the cyphertext file.  That way the receiver just treats the first 8 bytes (DES) or 16 bytes (AES) as the IV and the rest of the file as the actual cyphertext.

Use the same format for the IV as you are using for the cyphertext: Base64, hex, byte data or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can use any format you want, as long as the decrypting part of the program knows how to read it. For efficiency, having the initialization vector before the data seems a good idea.

If you want to encrypt files, a good idea would be to not create your own format (which leads to you having to do decisions like the one here), but use an existing file format (which then also is a cryptographic protocol).

I recommend the [OpenPGP message format, as defined in RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) (or some subset thereof, if you don't need all features). This also has the advantage that your clients then can decrypt your files using any OpenPGP implementation (like pgp or gpg), if your program somehow ceases to work (of course, only if they have the key/password).

Answer (score 1):

you should be fine if you store the IV together with the encrypted data in the file ...

Comment: But how? First line IV and the rest should be binary data?

Comment: @MartyIX ... depending on what else you are storing there, you may want to write some header, containing information about the file layout ... or you could just dump everything (iv,data) into the file byte by byte ... or you could use xml ... endless possibilities ...

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just wondering whether there's a standard that is commonly used. Because if there is then my service is useless with my custom output implementation. A user won't be able to use it in his/her another program.

Comment: well, if you have a public documentation for your format, there should be no problem