# .Net Symmetric Encryption - Initailization Vector

Tags: .net

How is an initialization vector made know to the "decrytor" if is it is supposed to be changed every time?

`var encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, initializationVector)`
.
.

```
var decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, initializationVector)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send it to the other side... for instance as a known, fixed-size header in the data stream.
Unlike the Key, an IV does not have to be kept secret.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8226051/60761).